# specifying a webdriver locator in a function call

Tags: python, selenium, wait

I was looking for a suggestion on how to wait for a particular page element is clickable, and found this post:

[Explicit wait in Python Selenium with page object model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48688453/explicit-wait-in-python-selenium-with-page-object-model?rq=1)

The code given in the post was:

```
def _wait_and_click(self, locator, timeout):
    try:
        wait = WebDriverWait(self.driver, timeout)
        wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((locator["by"], locator["value"]))).click()
    except TimeoutException:
        return False
    return True
```

This looks exactly like what I need, however how do I call it?
I tried:
    _wait_and_click(self, (By.ID, 'next-button'), 60)

and got the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "testProject.py", line 65, in test002_new_project
    _wait_and_click(self, (By.ID,'next-button'), 60)
  File "testProject.py", line 23, in _wait_and_click
    wait.until(expected_conditions.element_to_be_clickable((locator["by"], locator["value"]))).click()
TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not str
```

So how should I be calling the function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You used a tuple() instead of a dict()

```
_wait_and_click({'by': By.ID, 'value': 'next-button'}, 60)
```