# Selecting dynamic react dropdown in python selenium pytest

Tags: python-3.x, selenium, selenium-chromedriver, pytest

Hi i am trying to select a dynamic dropdown built in react while making a python selenium pytest framework. I am facing an issue in first sending keys in the dropdown so options are loaded and then selecting particular option. The dropdown database is very huge as it consists values for certain big organisations, hence 3 words are required so as to load specific values. Also if anyone can let me know how to let driver wait in page object model.

Comment: If possible, post the website link (or at least a sample url identical to the one so as to inspect). You can use explicit wait (`webdriverwait`). This might help you out [SO Archive Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48688453/explicit-wait-in-python-selenium-with-page-object-model)

Answer (score 0):

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service 
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
url=........
ser = Service(seleniumpath)
driver=webdriver.Chrome(service = ser)
driver.get(url)
WebDriverWait(driver, 7).until(lambda x:x.find_element(By.CSS_SELECTOR,'title'))
    #By support XPATH CLASS_NAME CSS_SELECTOR ID........
    #7  within the second time finding the elements 
driver.close()
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).